# Downloading Assets from AEM DAM

Tags: java, servlets, maven-3, aem, maven-plugin

Trying to do the this link: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem64_download_dam_assets.html

Everything is going well until I reach the last part:

```
mvn -PautoInstallPackage install
```

I can't get that to work. I'm getting POM errors. I've been searching for hours still to no avail. I'm getting missing jar error.

I was hoping the error can be solved like NPM Install but it's not :(

Any help?

-I've already installed MAVEN and copied the setting.xml to /.m2/ directory.

[image: A sneak peek of my error.]

[image: More Screenshots]

!UPDATE!
[image: Update]

passed cur when I downgraded to JDK 8,
seems to me like JDK 8 is more stable.

But now I'm stuck on UI apps. anymore solutions?

UPDATE:
I think I found a solution.

[image: screenshot]

How can I change that Localhost install location? that's not my install location.
I'm running that command with the
    mvn -PautoInstallPackage install
line. how can I modify port?

Comment: A test has failed. You should be able to find details just above the output visible in your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added screen shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
First Solution: Downgrading from Java10 to Java8
Second Solution: Editing my buildDirectory from my POM file

Hope this helps others! ask question if you have ;) maybe I've been thru it already